# Javascript post request method not allowed

Tags: javascript, http-post, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to make an authentication app in javascript, but I'm getting a 405 Method not allowed error.

```
    <form id="main-form" name="main-form">
        <input id="username" autocomplete="off">
        <input id="password" autocomplete="off" type="password">
        <input id="password-confirm" autocomplete="off" type=password>
        <input  id="register-proceed" type="submit" value="REGISTER">
        <script src="js/auth/register.js"></script>
    </form>
```

Js file:

```
const form = document.getElementById('main-form')

form.addEventListener('submit', registerUser)

async function registerUser(event) {
    
    event.preventDefault()
    const username = document.getElementById('username').value
    const password = document.getElementById('password').value

    await fetch('/api/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username,
            password
        })
    })

}
```

Edit: I added the backend code:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.post('/api/register', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.json( {status: "ok"})
})

app.listen(9999, () => {
    console.log("Server up at port 9999")
})
```

EDIT: I found out that the problem is with POST requests, when I do any other request it works fine. Any solutions?

Comment: This might be a CORS error

Comment: Did you try to send the request via Postman?

Answer (score 0):

Your JS is incorrect

```js
fetch('/api/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "username": "YOUR_USERNAME",
            "password": "YOUR_PASSWORD"
        })
    })
```

Comment: What was incorrect about it? The `body` looked good, so this isn't necessary.

Comment: Nope, still the same result.

Comment: @Shivam This is not a valid JSON or not even an object.

```javascript
JSON.stringify({
            username,
            password
        })
```

Comment: What part of it is not valid?

Comment: both JSON and javascript object is a key-value structure. So you tell me where is the key and which one is the value for {username, password}?

Comment: @JeduMiSePalacinke 405 is methods not allow. Have you tried to use Postman to post a request to your dev server?